# Yii2 swiftmailer: get generated message

Tags: php, yii2, swiftmailer

I'd like to save into database the sent emails. I'm using Yii2 with Swiftmailer and my question is: is there any way to get the genereated htmlBody (the template with variables) after or before send?

If not how can I generate a view file into `$message` variable in a model class?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just save message before send. If you save the content as .EML file it works perfectly.

```
$email = Yii::$app->mailer->compose('simpleEmail')
    ->setFrom(['sender@senderdomain.com' => 'Sender Name'])
    ->setTo($emails_array)
    ->setSubject('subject');

$mailMessage = $email->toString();

$email->send();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can easily save Html Body of email generated

If you are have your email sending code in `/controllers/XyzController.php`:

**STEP:1**

```
    $param = 'some value';
    $path_to_email_template = '@app/mail/layouts/eg';
    $message = $this->renderPartial($path_to_email_template, ['param'=>$param]);
    echo "$message"; // test
    \Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
      ->setTo('sohelahmed@peerbits.com')
      ->setFrom('example@mail.com')
      ->setSubject('Hello')
      ->setHtmlBody($message)
      ->send();
```

**STEP:2**

Now you have your email body stored in `$message` variable and you can save it like

```
$model = new Somemodel; // consider Somemodel model
$model->html_content = $message; // consider Somemodel model have attribute 'html_content'
// assign another properties too, if any
$model->save(true);
// Great, email body saved in DataBase, if no validation error occurs. If validation error occurs use print_r($model->errors); to debug
```

And if you are sending mail in any view file, then in `/views/xyx/index.php` (say in index.php file)

Replace third line of STEP:1

```
$message = $this->renderPartial($path_to_email_template, ['param'=>$param]);
```

by

```
$message = $this->render($path_to_email_template, ['param'=>$param]);
```

and go on further.
That's it.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it's possible. But you can set 'useFileTransport' => true in the configuration of the mailer component. This will save the mails in the runtime/mail folder instead of sending them. The saved files are in the eml-format which can be viewed for example by thunderbird. To change the path of the folder use the property 'fileTransportPath'.

As far as i know you can't do both send & saving them to filesystem.

Hope i could help with your first question.

Answer (score -1):

You can read about fileTransportCallback:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-mail-basemailer.html#$fileTransportCallback-detail

In return you will get callback with `$mailer`, and `$message`.
Save it to database

Answer (score -2):

You can save the HTML in a view file :

```
$message = Yii::$app->mailer->compose('myview', ['param1'=>'param'])
  ->setTo('...')
  ->setFrom('...')
  ->setSubject('');

//And then maybe you can get the textBody
$body = $message->getTextBody();//I'm not sure for this part

return $message->send();
```

The view file (myview") should be in "mail" folder (/mail/myview.php).
I didn't test it.

See doc : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-mailing.html#composing-mail-content

Comment: This is not working: Calling unknown method: yii\swiftmailer\Message::getTextBody()